# Automatic replies do not send to external people emailing in

Tags: exchange, auto-reply

Automatic replies work for anyone emailing someone internally.

However, when an external customer emails in there is no automatic reply sent to them, there are no error messages or bouncebacks, nothing.

Been happening for the past few days, no changes had been made to the exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the auto reply on the "outside organization" tab?

Answer (score 1):

An Exchange Administrator can check the configuration of a given mailbox using PowerShell:

```
Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity <mailboxid>
```

There are several properties here, and they all work in different ways based on how it is enabled.  What you want to watch out for:

- `AutoReplyState`: Enabled/Disabled
- `ExternalAudience`: None (default), Known (contacts in address book), All

Please pay attention to the Enabled state vs. Scheduled state.  It is a little bit goofy.

Further reference on Technet: [Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217(v=exchg.150).aspx)

**ProTip**: If you ever need to set a message for another user, draft the message in Word, and Save As HTML.  You can import the HTML into a variable using Get-Content and then assign the InternalMessage/ExternalMessage using this variable.    This method ensures the best experience for web/email, even though the HTML output from Word is gross.

Comment: I liked your tip.